# how to configure zf cli tool to recognize multiple application sub-directories?

Tags: php, zend-framework, backend

I am developing an application using Zend Framework 1.11.10. I have used  [this article](http://blog.ricky-stevens.com/zend-framework-multiple-applications/) to make sub-directory tree. The problem I'm facing now is that I can't use provided CLI ZF tool to generate controller-view stubs. I am developing an application which's functionality will vary depending on the accessing method. When the base www.example.com address will be prepended with letter m (m.example.com) I would like to serve mobile content which will be lightweight tailored for smart-phones. Please tell me, how to manage to change cli zf tool configuration, I would like to be able to issue commands similar with ***zf create view|controller|action ObjectName --application_name desktop|mobile***

```
└─ rdp
    ├─ .svn
    ├─ application
    │  ├─ .svn
    │  ├─ desktop
    │  │  ├─ .svn
    │  │  ├─ configs
    │  ├─ controllers
    │  │  ├─ models
    │  │  └─ views
    │  └─ mobile
    │     ├─ .svn
    │     ├─ configs
    │     ├─ controllers
    │     ├─ models
    │     └─ views
    ├─ docs
    ├─ library
    ├─ public
    └─ tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use modules for this. Zend_Tool supports creating controllers within modules. The [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html) has a good explanation.

To use Zend_Tool to create the mobile module:

```
zf create module mobile
```

To use Zend_Tool to create the IndexController within the mobile module:

```
zf create controller Index 1 mobile
```

(The "1" is important!)